# SourceTree push timeout

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I new to new to git and newer to SourceTree on OS X. Hopefully this will make some sense. I am trying to push a large number of files (154 new) to the origin/master on github and it appears that the push fails due to a timeout on the server.  I'm happy to roll things back if necessary and only push a few files, but my local master keeps falling further 'behind' as origin/master is updated by others on the project. As seen in the screenshot, I am now 8 'ahead' and really need to sync my local repository with the master soon. Everything is backed up so I'm OK with rolling back my attempts at push; just not sure about the best/correct way to get out of this hole.

[image: screen capture of SourceTree state]

Comment: Can you post the git error message